# Hide button with CSS in Communities

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, community, css

I want to ask for any advice and suggestion.
Currently we are facing trivial but in a same time a bit more complicated situation.

Situation:
We have custom button in communities which we want to hide for specific users.

Problem:
We should not create new profiles of restrict flow to specific users.

I was trying to play with CSS selectors and found a way how to hide it :

```
.branding-actions.actionMenu.popupTargetContainer.uiPopupTarget.uiMenuList.forceActionsDropDownMenuList.uiMenuList--left.uiMenuList--default [title="Prequalify"]{display:none;}
```

But now is the question, is there any way with aura component or potentionally LWC, to make this conditional, so this CSS will execute during rendering page only if example profile=Internal_User ?

Thank you for any advice, this field is a bit new to me in way of development and I will really appreciate any advice.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Audiences + Page Variations.

The area where you do this is here:

[image]

Click on the orange highlighted area and you get this:

[image]

This allows you to basically assign different VERSIONS of a page depending on certain conditions (in this case the profile of the user).

Now what you'll need to do is to assign a component or a page theme that allows you to use your CSS to target one of these page variations, but not the other.

Using a different contentlayout is a good way to do this, as it wraps the page - which means you can see the difference for different audiences.

Give this a try and let me know how it goes.